# A word that has a similar meaning to contain someone, as in a loving and understanding way

Tags: synonyms

I had the same issue with this word and I rememeber finding it and wtiting it somewhere but sadly it is nowhere to be found. Anyway, the word can be literally translated as "contain". I have spent last night trying to find it again but I failed, the closest I got was embrace or encompass.

The context I am looking for is something along the lines of, 'a good parent knows how to *contain* his son with love, compassion and understanding'
In addition to contain, what other words could convey a similar meaning when used in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The verb **[surround](https://www.google.com/search?q=surrounded%20with%20love&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiclefQ2a7gAhWSL1AKHUVYDDMQ_AUIEygA&biw=1289&bih=808)** is often used in the way you're looking for, "to surround someone with love", and it is a synonym of **contain** and **encompass**.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "imbue." It means "to make someone have a particular feeling."

"A good parent knows how to **imbue** his son with love, compassion and understanding."